# How to get a specific value from arraylist with different types of elements?

Tags: java, arraylist, element

please help me , i can understand how to get just one of the value of the element and collect it with the same type of other element , in the task i need to take weight and price.

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    Products p1 = new Products(1, "tomatoes-", 90, 75, 45, 0.0, 0.98);
    Products p2 = new Products(2, "potatoes-", 80, 54, 35, 8.90, 0.67);
    Products p3 = new Products(3, "melon-", 123, 60, 100, 0.08, 0.70);
    Products p4 = new Products(4, "eggplant-", 30, 50, 56, 4.78, 0.60);

    ArrayList<Products> product = new ArrayList<Products>();
    product.add(p1);
    product.add(p2);
    product.add(p3);
    product.add(p4);

    Iterator itr = product.iterator();
     while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Products pt = (Products) itr.next();

          //sum of the weight if product weight is more than 100g 
            if (pt.weight > 0.1) {
             double sumWeight =+pt.weight ;
             System.out.println(sumWeight);
            }

            //show products
            System.out.printf("id: " + pt.id + " name: " + pt.name + " " + pt.height + "x" +pt.lenght 
            + "x"+ pt.width + "mm" + " weight: " + df.format(pt.weight) + "kg" + " price: " 
            +df.format(pt.price)+ "lv.\n");

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class Products {

    int id;
    String name;
    int height;
    int lenght;
    int width;
    double weight;
    double price;

    public Products(int id, String name, int height, int lenght, int width, double weight, double price) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.lenght = lenght;
        this.width = width;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.price = price;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to add the weights of all products, if weight is more than 100g?

Comment: No, for all the  products over 100g i have to find the total amount of the weight and the same for the price

Comment: Total price for all the product which has weight more that 100g right?

Comment: yes and the weight for those products

Answer (score 1):

Does this helps?

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Products {
    int id;
    String name;
    int height;
    int lenght;
    int width;
    double weight;
    double price;
    DecimalFormat df;

    public Products(int id, String name, int height, int lenght, int width, double weight, double price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.lenght = lenght;
        this.width = width;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.price = price;
        this.df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + this.id + " name: " + this.name + " " + this.height + "x" + this.lenght
                + "x" + this.width + "mm" + " weight: " + df.format(this.weight) + "kg" + " price: "
                + df.format(this.price) + "lv.";
    }
}

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Products p1 = new Products(1, "tomatoes-", 90, 75, 45, 0.0, 0.98);
        Products p2 = new Products(2, "potatoes-", 80, 54, 35, 8.90, 0.67);
        Products p3 = new Products(3, "melon-", 123, 60, 100, 0.08, 0.70);
        Products p4 = new Products(4, "eggplant-", 30, 50, 56, 4.78, 0.60);

        List<Products> product = new ArrayList<>();
        product.add(p1);
        product.add(p2);
        product.add(p3);
        product.add(p4);

        double sumWeight = 0;
        double sumPrice = 0;
        for (Products pt : product) {
            //sum of the weight if product weight is more than 100g
            if (pt.weight > 0.1) {
                sumWeight += pt.weight;
                sumPrice += pt.price;
            }

            //show products
            System.out.println(pt);
        }

        System.out.println("\nAggregated attribute ---");
        System.out.println("Total Wight: " + sumWeight);
        System.out.println("Total Price: " + sumPrice);
    }
}
```

Note: You don’t actually need iterator to iterate through a List. Also use `toString()` if you want to format your class

Comment: this just take the weight and the price of the element it doesn't calculate them

Comment: i could fine it like that  double sumWeight = p2.weight + p4.weight;
                                        double sumPrice = p2.price + p4.price;

Comment: but if you don't know which is the element (p1,p2,p3,p4) you need how it wil be ? that is what i am trying to do

Comment: what do mean by `don't know which is the element` here are we are iterating over all the products and checking whether it has weight greater than 100g, then only calculate the sum of price and weight. Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: I have changed `=+` to `+=`. I copied the code from you. Can you please check now.

Answer (score 1):

The issues that you need to fix are:

- `sumWeight` has to be defined outside the loop. Otherwise it can't accumulate the weights of several products.
- `sumPrice` has to be defined similarly
- `sumWeight=+pt.weight` does not add a new weight to the sum. You may have confused `=+` with the `+=` operator. You could use the `+=` operator to do it, but often it's clearer to spell it out completely and write `sumWeight = sumWeight + pt.weight`. That way there's no chance of confusion.

Here's the minimal but working code:

```
    double sumWeight = 0;
    double sumPrice = 0;
    for (Products p : product) {
        if (p.weight > 0.1) {
            sumWeight = sumWeight + p.weight;
            sumPrice = sumPrice + p.price;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total weight=" + sumWeight);
    System.out.println("Total price=" + sumPrice);
```

Comment: I replied with the same. I also haven’t noticed he used `=+` instead of  `+=`. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: yes i didn't notice the sign, thank you so much it work